# Get response when soap call returns (400) Bad Request

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl, bad-request

I am calling an external service in my C# .net project. My project is sending user input to that external service. When there is an error in the user input, for example an invalid phone number, the external web service is returning a 400 Bad Request error. When I do the same call in SoapUI, I am also getting a response XML from that webservice, telling me what user input was wrong.

In my C# project, where I added the wsdl as service reference, I am also getting the 400 Bad Request, but it crashes at that point. But I can't find how I can get the response in that case, so I can show it to the users of my application. Is there any way how I can get the response from the external webservice?

Comment: it crashed? or did it throw an exception?

Comment: I am getting a System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.'

Comment: well after 10 years here on SO you should know the game: Add details to the question. The comment section is not the right place for it